# Finding certain pattern of bits in an unsigned integer

Tags: c

I am reviewing for an exam and have a practice problem that I'm stuck on.

I need to write the function `find_sequence(unsigned int num, unsigned int patter) {}.`

I have tried comparing `num & (pattern << i) == (pattern << i)` and other things like that but it keeps saying there is a pattern when there isn't. I see why it is doing that but I can not fix it.

The `num` I'm using is `unsigned int a = 82937` and I'm searching for pattern `unsigned int b = 0x05`.

```
Pattern:         00000000000000000000000000000101
Original bitmap: 00000000000000010100001111111001
```

The code so far:

```
int find_sequence(unsigned int num, unsigned int pattern)
{
        for (int i=0; i<32; i++)
        {
                if ((num & (pattern << i)) == (pattern << i))
                {
                        return i;
                }
        }

        return -9999;
}

int
main()
{
    unsigned int a = 82937;
    unsigned int b = 0x05;

    printf("Pattern: ");
    printBits(b);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Original bitmap: ");
    printBits(a);
    printf("\n");

    int test = find_sequence(a, b);
    printf("%d\n", test);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I have so far. This keeps returning 3, and I see why but I do not know how to avoid it.

Comment: suggestion #1 - show us the code you have written that doesnt work

Comment: i did nt look, but perhaps you will find what you need here https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: I added my code.

Comment: You're getting an answer of 3 because `101 << 3 = 101000` and `101000 & 111101 = 101000`. You need to mask off the unused bits of `pattern` somehow.

Comment: Your pattern is not a mask. To get mask out of given pattern you have to find last set bit and derive a mask from it. Let’s assume we have a function *int fls(unsigned long value)*, which returns 0, if value is 0, and last set bit number + 1 otherwise. Then *mask  = (1 << fls(pattern)) - 1;*, and *if ((num & (mask << i)) == (pattern << i))*. Of course you have to take care about 0 case, and better to use right shifts than left to prevent overflows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case you could make a bitmask that 0's out all the spaces you aren't looking for so in this case

Pattern: 00000000000000000000000000000101

Bitmask: 00000000000000000000000000000111

So in the case of the number you are looking at

Original: 00000000000000010100001111111001

If you and that with this bitmask you end of with

Number after &: 00000000000000000000000000000001

And compare the new number with your pattern to see if equal.

Then >> the original number

Original:      00000000000000010100001111111001

Right shifted: 00000000000000001010000111111100

And repeat the & and compare to check the next 3 numbers in the sequence.

Comment: So you are saying do bitmask & original? I don't understand how you end up with 00000000000000000000000000000001 if you did that.

Comment: Sorry I had that backwards.  I changed the bitmask.  It will work now to get the last three of the pattern. @Darren

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++)
    {
            if ((num & (pattern << i)) == (pattern << i))
```

is bad:
- it works only when pattern consists of `1` entirely
- you generate at the end of the loop `pattern << 31` which is `0` when pattern is even. Condition will hold every time then.

Knowing the length of the pattern would simplify the loop above; just go until `32 - size`.  When not given by the API, the length can be calculated either by a `clz()` function or manually by looping over the bits.

Now, you can generate the mask as `mask = (1u << length) - 1u` (note: you have to handle the `length == 32` case in a special way) and write

```
for (int i=0; i < (32 - length); i++)
{
        if ((num & (mask << i)) == (pattern << i))
```

or

```
for (int i=0; i < (32 - length); i++)
{
        if (((num >> i) & mask) == pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

`((num & (pattern << i)) == (pattern << i))` won't give you the desire results.

Let's say you pattern is `0b101` and the value is `0b1111`, then

```
   0101   pattern
   1111   value
 & ----
   0101   pattern
```

Even though the value has not the pattern `0b101`, the check would return true.

You've got to create a mask where all bits of the pattern (until the most
significant bit) are 1 and the rest are 0. So for the pattern `0b101` the mask
must be `b111`.

So first you need to calculate the position of the most significant bit of the pattern, then create
the mask and then you can apply (bitwise AND) the mask to the value. If the
result is the same as the pattern, then you've found your pattern:

```
int find_sequence(unsigned int num, unsigned int pattern)
{
    unsigned int copy = pattern;

    // checking edge cases
    if(num == 0 && pattern == 0)
        return 0;

    if(num == 0)
        return -1;

    // calculating msb of pattern
    int msb = -1;
    while(copy)
    {
        msb++;
        copy >>= 1;
    }

    printf("msb of pattern at pos: %d\n", msb);

    // creating mask
    unsigned int mask = (1U << msb + 1) - 1;

    int pos = 0;
    while(num)
    {

        if((num & mask) == pattern)
            return pos;

        num >>= 1;
        pos++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Using this function I get the value 14, where your `0b101` pattern is found in
`a`.

Comment: You have an overflow condition if msb = 31. That’s why I told in my comment about right shifts. Moreover some compilers have intrinsic to find last set bit.

Comment: @0andriy you're right, I didn't thought about msb == 31. I'll fix the code later, right now I'm at work.